# create csv from dictionaries of dataframes and drop header

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create/save new csv dataframes from two dictionaries. The new dataframe should have the values of each dictionary according to the dict keys. Here is an example of my dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {
     '1': 3.84,
     '45': 4.9,
     '135': 6.7
}

dict2 = {
    '1': pd.DataFrame([[101,        105,        106 ],
                        [245,        134,        96  ],
                        [175,        105,        200 ]], 
                    columns=['AST_0-1'   ,'AST_10-1'   , 'AST_110-1']),

    '45': pd.DataFrame([[101,        105,        106 ],
                        [245,        134,        96  ],
                        [175,        105,        200 ]],
                    columns=['AST_0-45'  ,'AST_10-45'  , 'AST_110-45']),

    '135': pd.DataFrame([[101,      105,        106   ],
                        [245,      134,        96    ],
                        [175,      105,        200   ]],
                    columns=['AST_0-135' ,'AST_10-135' , 'AST_110-135'])
}
```

My final dataframes should have the values from each dictionaries key. This would be an example of one of the dataframes (key =1 from dict1 and dict2):

```
3.84

101        105        106 

245        134        96

175        105        200
```

I was able to "group" both dictionaries by key using this code:

```
dict3 = defaultdict(list)

for d in (dict1,dict2):

   for key, value in d.items():

       dict3[key].append(value)
```

However my dict3 has the headers of the dataframes in dict 2.

```
   defaultdict(list,
     {'1': [3.84,
        AST_0-1   AST_10-1    AST_110-1 \
     1    101        105        106 
     2    245        134        96
     3    175        105        200 ],

   '45': [4.9,
       AST_0-45  AST_10-45  AST_110-45 \
     1    101        105        106 
     2    245        134        96
     3    175        105        200 ],

   '135': [6.7,
       AST_0-135 AST_10-135 AST_110-135 \
     1      101      105        106 
     2      245      134        96
     3      175      105        200 ]})
```

Is there a way to group both dictionaries without the header and then save each key as new csv dataframe?

Comment: I don't really understand your expected output. Should the values of dict1 be part of the dataframe? Also if you want to get rid of column names and index / save as csv, shall the newly created df be saved as string?

Comment: Yes, the values of dict1 should be part of the final dataframe. I am saving as csv but eventually I will use this output as txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some misunderstanding of what a CSV file is -- The output you show is simply the `repr()` of your dictionary, which in turn shows the `repr()` of everything it contains, i.e. you see the keys (e.g. `'1'`), and the values of the keys (the lists). Inside the list, you have a single number (e.g. `3.84`) and the dataframe.

If you want a csv file, you need to create one. To do this, let's create a function that writes a CSV file given a file handle, a dataframe, and the number using pandas's inbuilt `to_csv()` with `header=False` and `index=False` to suppress the header row and index columns, and `sep='\t'` to separate columns by a tab:

```
def write_to_csv(file_handle, df, number):
    file_handle.write(f"{number}\n")
    df.to_csv(file_handle, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

Now, loop over the keys in *one* of your dicts, and call the function:

```
for k in dict1:
    file_name = f"{k}.csv"
    with open(file_name, "w") as out_file:
        write_to_csv(out_file, dict2[k], dict1[k])
```

Which will write three files with the following contents:
1.csv:

```
3.84
101 105 106
245 134 96
175 105 200
```

45.csv

```
4.9
101 105 106
245 134 96
175 105 200
```

135.csv

```
6.7
101 105 106
245 134 96
175 105 200
```